# Read specific files from Multiple flat files in one folder ,with different different names an different different architecture in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

Hi i have some flat files in one folder by name as given below..

```
C_Report-oct18.csv
C_Report-Nov18.csv
Gs_1012_Report-apr17.csv
Gs_1013_Report-apr17.csv
Gs_Price_Report-may18.csv
```

Here all files have different types of column with different count,name,datatypes,
but need to read only "Gs_1012_report,Gs_1013_report" like files..and want 1012,1013 codes in one separate column also..

Answer (score 0):

SSIS connection managers are static - they are not dynamic, which means that you will have to create a connection for each file where the columns do not all match.

Now, assuming that you have 100s of files for each file layout then you can create a connection manager for each file layout and then add a foreach file enumerator to loop over all of the files, read them in, and do something with their data.

**Update**

Allow me to clarify my answer based on your comment. The connection manager is static with respect `Architecture` of the file. Any attempt to read in a file with different names, ordering, or meta data of the columns, or outright file types, will result in an error. So, if what you mean by files having different `Architectures`, then I understand you to be saying that what you are referring to is a change in any of the items I just mentioned.

If this is not correct, then you need to update your answer to specify what you mean by different `Architecture`. Note: I do not consider different file names, as you have provided, to be different `Architectures` - they are just different file names. The Connection manager itself can be parameterized to allow for looping over different file names via the ConnectionString property. As you are aware, there are other properties that can be parameterized.

Comment: Thanks For reply weezy, but just for your correction in ssis connections can be dynamic by variables ..for that we can go in connection properties>expressions>choose connectionstring from list and provide your variable of connection path.